# How to fix "Gtk-CRITICAL **: 00:18:45.249: gtk_widget_queue_draw_area: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed"

Tags: c, gtk3, cairo, glade

I am writing GTK3 C program using Glade, which will draw rectangle, when button is pressed. It draws rectangle, but with problems.

I am getting this in the terminal, when calling rectangle drawing function:

```
(Logika.run:8416): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 00:30:59.112: gtk_widget_queue_draw_area: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

There is visual representation of the problem (I only clicked once) (sorry for low fps
[image: There is visual representation of the problem (I only clicked once) (sorry for low fps)]
As you can see, it draws a rectangle, but there is big delay.

I have tracked down problem to "gtk_widget_queue_draw_area", however I have no clue how to fix it. When I used this code without Glade, it worked without problems. Code is full of other things (like timer), so please, ignore those parts. Please pay attention to "Cairo Draw stuff".
There is C code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>


#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>



//==============================================================Timer=stuff==================================================================================
unsigned char isTimerRunning = 0;
int tempx = 0;
int tempy = 0;




gint TimerCallback (gpointer data)
{



    if (isTimerRunning == 1)
    {

        g_print("Timer click\n");

        //timer test
        if (tempx > 1300)
        {
            tempx = 0;
            tempy = tempy + 5;

        }
        //draw_brush (DrawArea, tempx, tempy);
        //draw_rectangle (DrawArea, tempx, tempy, 5, 5, 0.5, 0.5, 0);
        tempx = tempx + 5;
        //tempy = tempy + 5;








        return 1;
    } else
    {
        return 0;
    }

}

void StartTimer ()
{
    if (isTimerRunning == 0)
    {
        isTimerRunning = 1;
        g_timeout_add (100, TimerCallback, NULL);  //17 = 60fps

    }

}

void StopTimer ()
{
    isTimerRunning = 0;
}




//=======================================================================


//====================Cairo=Draw=stuff============================
static cairo_surface_t *surface = NULL;
GtkWidget *MainDrawArea;

static void clear_surface (void)
{
  cairo_t *cr;

  cr = cairo_create (surface);

  cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 1, 1, 1);
  cairo_paint (cr);

  cairo_destroy (cr);
}

/* Create a new surface of the appropriate size to store our scribbles */
gboolean configure_event_cb (GtkWidget *widget,GdkEventConfigure *event, gpointer data)
{
  if (surface)
    cairo_surface_destroy (surface);

  surface = gdk_window_create_similar_surface (gtk_widget_get_window (widget),
                                               CAIRO_CONTENT_COLOR,
                                               gtk_widget_get_allocated_width (widget),
                                               gtk_widget_get_allocated_height (widget));

  /* Initialize the surface to white */
  clear_surface ();

  /* We've handled the configure event, no need for further processing. */
  return TRUE;
}

/* Redraw the screen from the surface. Note that the ::draw
 * signal receives a ready-to-be-used cairo_t that is already
 * clipped to only draw the exposed areas of the widget
 */
gboolean draw_cb (GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data)
{
  cairo_set_source_surface (cr, surface, 0, 0);
  cairo_paint (cr);

  return FALSE;
}

/* Draw a rectangle on the surface at the given position */
static void draw_brush (GtkWidget *widget, gdouble x, gdouble y)
{
  cairo_t *cr;

  /* Paint to the surface, where we store our state */
  cr = cairo_create (surface);

  cairo_rectangle (cr, x - 3, y - 3, 6, 6);
  cairo_fill (cr);

  cairo_destroy (cr);

  /* Now invalidate the affected region of the drawing area. */
  gtk_widget_queue_draw_area (widget, x - 3, y - 3, 6, 6);
}



//========================




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkBuilder      *builder; 
    GtkWidget       *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "Resources/GUI_design.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window_main"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    g_object_unref(builder);



    //g_signal_connect (gl_area, "render", G_CALLBACK (render), NULL);




    gtk_widget_show(window);                
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

// called when window is closed
void on_window_main_destroy()
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}


void TestButton_clicked()
{
    g_print("Test button is pressed\n");

    //draw_rectangle (DrawArea, 50, 50, 20, 20, 0.5, 0.5, 0);
    //draw_callback(DrawArea,cr2);
    draw_brush (MainDrawArea, 100, 100);





}

void Debug_startTimer_activate()
{
    g_print("Timer start\n");
    StartTimer ();
}

void Debug_stopTimer_activate()
{
    g_print("Timer stop\n");
    StopTimer ();
}





gboolean Test_event ()
{
    g_print("Test Event\n");
    //printf ("print f test", 20);
    //sprintf("print f test ", "%d", event->x);
    //Test_event


}

//Reģistrē peles klikšķi
gboolean button_press_event_cb (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event, gpointer data)
//gboolean button_press_event_cb (GdkEventButton *event)
{

    printf("[Click] Mouse X: %f\n", event->x);
    printf("[Click] Mouse Y: %f\n", event->y);

    return TRUE;



}

//Reģistrē peles kustību
gboolean motion_notify_event_cb (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventMotion *event, gpointer data)
{
    printf("[Move] Mouse X: %f\n", event->x);
    printf("[Move] Mouse Y: %f\n", event->y);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Glade design code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkImage" id="NOT_gate_image">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="pixbuf">Standard_gates_images/Not_gate.png</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkPopover" id="StandartGatesChooseButton_popover1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="StandartGatesChooseButton_popover1_box">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Not vārti</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="image">NOT_gate_image</property>
            <property name="always_show_image">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">OR vārti</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">AND vārti</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkImage">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="stock">gtk-missing-image</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkImage">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="stock">gtk-missing-image</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window_main">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Logika komponentu simulators</property>
    <property name="default_width">1920</property>
    <property name="default_height">1080</property>
    <property name="icon">icon.png</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window_main_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child type="titlebar">
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="MainBox">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkMenuBar" id="MenuBar">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_Datne</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem">
                        <property name="label">imagemenuitem</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="image">__glade_unnamed_27</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">False</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem">
                        <property name="label">gtk-open</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem">
                        <property name="label">gtk-save</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem">
                        <property name="label">gtk-save-as</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkSeparatorMenuItem">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem">
                        <property name="label">gtk-quit</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">R_ediģēt</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem">
                        <property name="label">gtk-cut</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem">
                        <property name="label">gtk-copy</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem">
                        <property name="label">gtk-paste</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem">
                        <property name="label">gtk-delete</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_Skats</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_Palīdzība</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem">
                        <property name="label">gtk-about</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="Debug">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Debug</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem">
                        <property name="label">Start timer</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">False</property>
                        <signal name="activate" handler="Debug_startTimer_activate" swapped="no"/>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem">
                        <property name="label">Stop timer</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">False</property>
                        <signal name="activate" handler="Debug_stopTimer_activate" swapped="no"/>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkPaned" id="MainPaned">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
            <property name="position">900</property>
            <property name="position_set">True</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkEventBox" id="GtkDrawingArea_EventBox">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <signal name="button-press-event" handler="button_press_event_cb" swapped="no"/>
                <signal name="motion-notify-event" handler="motion_notify_event_cb" swapped="no"/>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkDrawingArea" id="MainDrawArea">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <signal name="configure-event" handler="configure_event_cb" swapped="no"/>
                    <signal name="draw" handler="draw_cb" swapped="no"/>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="resize">True</property>
                <property name="shrink">True</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkBox" id="ControlBox">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="spacing">5</property>
                <property name="homogeneous">True</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkMenuButton" id="StandartGatesChooseButton">
                    <property name="label" translatable="yes">Standarta vārti</property>
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                    <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                    <property name="direction">up</property>
                    <property name="popover">StandartGatesChooseButton_popover1</property>
                    <child>
                      <placeholder/>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                  <packing>
                    <property name="expand">False</property>
                    <property name="fill">True</property>
                    <property name="position">0</property>
                  </packing>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkButton" id="TestButton">
                    <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                    <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                    <signal name="clicked" handler="TestButton_clicked" swapped="no"/>
                  </object>
                  <packing>
                    <property name="expand">False</property>
                    <property name="fill">True</property>
                    <property name="position">1</property>
                  </packing>
                </child>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="resize">False</property>
                <property name="shrink">False</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkImage">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="stock">gtk-missing-image</property>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: I fixed both problems here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53459739/gtkdrawingarea-wont-update-when-drawing-happens-if-glade-is-used