# GtkDrawingArea won't update when drawing happens if Glade is used

Tags: c, gtk3, glade

I have created very simple GTK3 C app with glade, which contains button and GtkDrawingArea (held together with GtkPaned). When button is presed, it should immediately draw a rectangle, however, it doesn't happen. It only happens, when mouse howers on GtkPaned split part (see .gif). If Glade is not used, then this problem doesn't exist.

How to fix this problem?

[image: A simple .gif]
 gif

C code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

//==============================================================Global=variables========================================================================
static cairo_surface_t *surface = NULL;
GtkWidget *DrawArea;

//==============================================================Functions===============================================================================


void clear_surface (void)
{
    cairo_t *cr;

    cr = cairo_create (surface);

    cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0, 1, 1);
    cairo_paint (cr);

    cairo_destroy (cr);
}

//Create a new surface of the appropriate size to store our scribbles
gboolean configure_event_cb (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventConfigure *event, gpointer data)
{
    if (surface)
    {
        cairo_surface_destroy (surface);
    }


    surface = gdk_window_create_similar_surface (gtk_widget_get_window (widget), CAIRO_CONTENT_COLOR, gtk_widget_get_allocated_width (widget), gtk_widget_get_allocated_height (widget));

    /* Initialize the surface to white */
    clear_surface ();

    /* We've handled the configure event, no need for further processing. */
    return TRUE;
}

/* Redraw the screen from the surface. Note that the ::draw
 * signal receives a ready-to-be-used cairo_t that is already
 * clipped to only draw the exposed areas of the widget
 */
gboolean draw_cb (GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data)
{
    cairo_set_source_surface (cr, surface, 0, 0);
    cairo_paint (cr);

    return FALSE;
}

//Draw a rectangle on the surface at the given position
void draw_brush (GtkWidget *widget, double x, double y)
{
    cairo_t *cr;

    /* Paint to the surface, where we store our state */
    cr = cairo_create (surface);

    cairo_rectangle (cr, x - 3, y - 3, 6, 6);
    cairo_fill (cr);

    cairo_destroy (cr);

    //Now invalidate the affected region of the drawing area.
    gtk_widget_queue_draw_area (widget, x - 3, y - 3, 6, 6);
}

void draw_rectangle (GtkWidget *widget, float posX, float posY, float length, float height, float colorR, float colorG, float colorB)
{
    cairo_t *cr;

    /* Paint to the surface, where we store our state */
    cr = cairo_create (surface);
    cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, colorR, colorG, colorB);

    cairo_rectangle (cr, posX, posY, length, height);
    cairo_fill (cr);

    cairo_destroy (cr);

    //Now invalidate the affected region of the drawing area.
    gtk_widget_queue_draw_area (widget, posX, posY, length, height);
}


//==================================Button=stuff==========================
void Button_clicked(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data)
{
    g_print("Clicked\n");
    draw_brush (DrawArea, 10, 10);
    //gtk_widget_queue_draw (window_main);
}





int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    GtkBuilder      *builder; 
    GtkWidget       *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    DrawArea = gtk_drawing_area_new ();
    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "Resources/GUI_design.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window_main"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    g_object_unref(builder);

    gtk_widget_show(window);                
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}




// called when window is closed
void on_window_main_destroy()
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}
```

Glade code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window_main">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="default_width">500</property>
    <property name="default_height">500</property>
    <property name="icon">icon.png</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window_main_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child type="titlebar">
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkPaned" id="paned">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <property name="position">300</property>
        <property name="position_set">True</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkDrawingArea" id="DrawArea">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <signal name="configure-event" handler="configure_event_cb" swapped="no"/>
            <signal name="draw" handler="draw_cb" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="resize">False</property>
            <property name="shrink">False</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="Button">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="Button_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="resize">True</property>
            <property name="shrink">True</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found and fixed the problem!!!!

int main now looks like this (1 line removed and 1 line added)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    GtkBuilder      *builder; 
    GtkWidget       *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    //DrawArea = gtk_drawing_area_new ();
    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "Resources/GUI_design.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window_main"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    DrawArea = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "DrawArea")); //This is very important

    g_object_unref(builder);

    gtk_widget_show(window);                
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Description what caused this problem: Glade and I created 2 separate pointers, and I only did stuff with my pointer, not Glade's. That important line connect together those 2 pointers and now it works. Juhū!

This tuturial helped me to fix the problem: https://prognotes.net/2016/03/gtk-3-c-code-hello-world-tutorial-using-glade-3/